# Why didn't I need to connect to database

Tags: node.js, mongoose, require

I am new to web development. I just made a user model and then required into the main app.js file. But I saw that while making the user model I didn't need to connect to the database for it but I have connected the database to the app.js file. Then I saw how to require() works I found that it first runs the module/file which we had required and then return the object which that file returns. So I thought that it must throw an error because it wouldn't have fount the connection to the database while making the user model.

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var passportlocalmongoose=require('passport-local-mongoose');

var userschema=new mongoose.Schema({
    username:String,
    password:String
});

userschema.plugin(passportlocalmongoose);
module.exports=mongoose.model('User',userschema);
```

Answer (score 0):

you're not connected because you're not providing the required parameter,
here , there are some steps you can use.
first of all install `express, mongoose and dotenv dependencies`, and  you will need a database URL in .env file

```
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const app = express();

dotenv.config();
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
})
  .then(() => process.stdout.write('DB Connection succesfully\n'));
const port =3000

app.listen(port, () => process.stdout.write(`Listening on port ${port} ... \n`));
export default app;
```

Comment: Actually my code is working but I was expecting an error. And the reason is that I am expecting error because when I require this file in my main app.js file then require() runs this file and returns the object. And acc to that this file must be run separately and as it is not connected to database so it must show error